# Rails nesting queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following models

```
class User << ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_many :acknowledgements
end

class Event << ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :acknowledgements
    has_many :tracks, through: event_track
end

class Acknowledgement << ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :event
end

class Track << ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :event_tracks
    has_many :events, through: event_tracks
end

class EventTrack << ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :event
    belongs_to :track
end
```

As shown above, a user may acknowledge attending an event. A track is a set of events, and an event can belong to multiple tracks. We say a user completes a track when the user acknowledges attending all events under that track.

My questions is, is there a way to find all tracks that a user has completed using the ActiveRecord query interface?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this starting the query from the tracks end, as that's the output you'd like returned:

```
user = User.first
Track.joins(events: :acknowledgements).where(complete: true, events: { acknowledgements: { user_id: user.id })
```

Here, you eager load tracks' events and their acknowledgements for performance purposes, then (making an assumption this column exists) check the track is complete and the events' acknowledgements contain your user.

The reason you check `user_id` in the `acknowledgements` table is to avoid having to preload the `users` in the query to improve performance.

Hope that helps - let me know how you get on or if you have any questions.